# clickevent to sub(folder)

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i click on medewerkers 1001 (a href link) it goes first to the folder `medewerker` and if i click it again then it goes to folder `1001` in `medewerkers`

how can i make sure i only need 1 click to go to `medewerkers` > `1001`

after first click

it goes to folder `medewerkers` instead of `1001`

my main code is here

http://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript

it's too much to copy paste it here

html:

```
 <ul id="linkjess">
      <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('medewerkers', '1000');">medewerkers 1000</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('medewerkers', '1001');">medewerkers 1001</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('medewerkers', '2001');">medewerkers 2001</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('kantoren', '101');">Kantoor 101</a></li>
    </ul>
```

script :

```
  function setfolder(type, id)
{ 
        $(".folder-box").each(function(index, element) {
          if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == type)
              {
                $(element).find("img").trigger("click")
              }
                if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == id)
                {
                   $(element).find("img").trigger("click")
                }
        })
}
```

how can i combine those 2 if's ?

Answer (score 0):

try using || operator , so if 'type' is undefined 'id' is taken

```
if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == (type || id)){
$(element).find("img").trigger("click")
}
```

Comment: but he must take the type and the id de type is the main folder en the id is the subfolder